# Project Euler 10: Summation of primes in Go

Tags: programming-challenge, primes, go

Here is my first try at Google's Go language, trying to solve Project Euler Problem 10:

> The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
>
> Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

Any suggestions on the style and usage (best practice) of Go?

```
package main

import "fmt"

var primes = []uint64{2, 3}

func CheckIfIsNewPrime(number uint64) bool {
    check_if_number_is_new_prime := false
    var remainder uint64 = 0

    for i := range primes {
        remainder = number % primes[i]
        if remainder == 0 {
            check_if_number_is_new_prime = false
            break
        } else {
            check_if_number_is_new_prime = true
        }
    }
    return check_if_number_is_new_prime
}

func FindNewPrime() uint64 {
    for counter := primes[len(primes)-1]; ; counter += 2 {
        if CheckIfIsNewPrime(counter) == true {
            return counter
        }
    }
    return 0
}

func main() {
    limit := 2000000
    var sum uint64
    sum = 5

    for i := 2; i < limit; i++ {
        primes = append(primes, FindNewPrime())
        sum += primes[len(primes)-1]
    }

    fmt.Println("sum: ", sum)

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Algorithm : really important**

What you want to to is to use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) because you already know an upper bound for the biggest number you're going to consider. Getting all the primes smaller than 2 millions is going to be straightforward.  This will solve your *process took too long* issue.

**Other things not as important**

- You could probably write the following function :

  ```
  func CheckIfIsNewPrime(number uint64) bool {
      check_if_number_is_new_prime := false
      var remainder uint64 = 0

      for i := range primes {
          remainder = number % primes[i]
          if remainder == 0 {
              check_if_number_is_new_prime = false
              break
          } else {
              check_if_number_is_new_prime = true
          }
      }
      return check_if_number_is_new_prime
  }
  ```

  in a more concise way (no real impact on performance)

  ```
  func CheckIfIsNewPrime(number uint64) bool {
      for i := range primes {
          if number % primes[i] == 0 {
              return false
          }
      }
      return true
  }
  ```
- I don't know anything about Go, but I guess

  ```
  if CheckIfIsNewPrime(counter) == true {
  ```

  could be written as

  ```
  if CheckIfIsNewPrime(counter) {
  ```

*As you go further in Project Euler, you'll see that most of the problem is to find the algorithm you want to use and not really to implement it.*

Comment: Thanks for the hints Josay, I incorporated them (except for the `else` loop falling out). I see the Euler Problems more of a way to learn a new language (and prepare a bit for possible job interviews, where i would have to solve problems out of my head). I would have never come up with the `Sieve` algo, hence the implementation by trial division. I impoved the performace a bit by setting an `upper bound` as I dont have to check against division by all previous primes.

I discovered a major misconception in my code: I tries to sum till the 2 millionth prime instead of all primes below 2 mio.

Comment: You're more than welcome. You'll really need to change the algorithm if you want to get any result (either for that problem or for a one later on). Also it's a classic algorithm which is always good to implement.